# How to use random.randint to find random 0 and 1 with not equal propbability

Tags: python, random, genetic-algorithm, deap

I am using [DEAP](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/deap) toolbox in Python for Genetic Algorithm.

`toolbox.register("attr_bool", random.randint, 0, 1)` is a function randomly chooses 0 and 1 for populations in GA. I want to force GA to choose 0 and 1 randomly but with for example 80% one and the rest zero.

I think `srng.binomial(X.shape, p=retain_prob)` is a choice, but I want to use `random.randint` function. Wondering how we can do that?

Comment: You could do something like `0 if random.randint(0, 4) == 0 else 1` or `0 if random.random() < 0.2 else 1`.

Comment: The problem is that when I use `0 if random.randint(0, 4) == 0 else 1` instead of `random.randint` in `toolbox.register("attr_bool", random.randint, 0, 1)`, it gives me the following error     `TypeError: the first argument must be callable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments to [`toolbox.register`](http://deap.gel.ulaval.ca/doc/default/api/base.html#deap.base.Toolbox.register) must be a function and the arguments that you want to pass to that function when you run it

Since `0 if random.randint(0, 4) == 0 else 1` is not a function (its a random number) you got an error. The fix is to package this expression inside a function that you can pass to `toolbox.register`:

```
# returns 1 with probability p and 0 with probability 1-p
def bernoulli(p):
    if random.random() < p:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

toolbox.register("attr_bool", bernoulli, 0.8)
```

Answer (score 2):

A natural way is to use the expression

```
1 if random.random() <= 0.8 else 0
```

You can abstract this into a function:

```
def bernoulli(p): return 1 if random.random() <= p else 0
```

Then `bernoulli(0.8)` will give 1 or 0 with the requisite probabilities. I am not familiar with the GA library you are using, but `bernoulli()` is callable hence it should work.

Comment: or, equivalently with `random.randint`:

`1 if random.randint(1,10) <= 8 else 0`

Comment: Please see the comment above

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That is a good suggestion but becomes unwieldy when the probability of 1 is no longer a rational number with a small denominator.

Comment: @AmnKh Shouldn't be the same error if you invoke it correctly, as detailed in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

`random.randint` does not provide such functionality, but if you wanted to stay in the `random` package, you could use `random.choice([0] * 1 + [1] * 4)`.

`numpy.random` also provides this functionality with `np.random.choice([0, 1], p=[0.2, 0.8])`.

Comment: If I stick on `np.random.choice`, how we can get a list of 100 elements? For example, I need a list with 100 size  which has a probability of [0.2 0.8]. I do not want to use loop.

Comment: `np.random.choice([0, 1], size=100, p=[0.2, 0.8])`

Comment: If you need it to be a list and not a numpy array, you should look at the `tolist` method. And of course if you want to generate random sample reproducibly, you should generate a `RandomState` object with a seed that you have set and use that to produce the samples.

Comment: Again the same problem, when I use `np.random.choice([0, 1], size=100, p=[0.2, 0.8])` instead of  `random.randint` in `toolbox.register("attr_bool", random.randint, 0, 1)`, the following error coming up:  `
TypeError: the first argument must be callable`

Comment: As @hugomg answered, the invocation of your random sampling function with `Toolbox.register` should be the function and then the args that would  be passed to that function, so if you wanted to use `np.random.choice` to produce an array of sample, something akin to `toolbox.register('attr_bool', np.random.choice, [0, 1], size=100, p=[0.2, 0.8])` would probably be appropriate.